# AngularJS with PHP to get and update a link

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to use AngularJS to access a PHP variable. Here is my HTML and Angular code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

Your Link: <div> <span ng-bind="fetchLink.link"></span></div>

</div>

<script>

  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$http', function($http) {
      var self = this;
      self.link = "";
      self.newTodo = {}; //Keys (as in key: value pairs) are automatically created when declared in form
      var fetchLink = function() {
        return $http.get('link.php').then(
            function(response) {
          self.link = response.data;
        }, function(errResponse) {
          console.error('Error while fetching notes');
        });
      };

}]);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my PHP:

```
<?php 
{ $link = 0x00;
    "link":[{$link}];
    $link= ($link + 1);
}
?>
```

I am trying to use the Angular code to access the 'link' variable that has to be updated each time it is accessed by any user (a hexidecimal value that is increased by 1). This is so that each user gets a unique link which they can access and share with their friends. When i preview the html page it just says your link: without any value next to it. I also thought about using a JSON object which I believe plays nicely with Angular, but I don't know if JSON objects can be updated with each use (because they are a client-side object, not server side).

Comment: it is extremely common to output json from server . Your php shown doesn't output anything and syntax is invalid also

Comment: @charlietfl Oh thanks, and I would be able to increment the link variable, like in my php code above?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $link = "http://example.com/".time();
   echo json_encode(array("link"=>$link));
?>
```

Use time() and something else like rand() for create unique link and return link in json using json_encode() function.

Comment: note that OP needs to access link property client side if they want that as value

Comment: what do you mean by if they want that as value?

Comment: `self.link = ""` looks like op expects string value assigned...not object

Comment: Yeah, i'm not using the php page as the actual page, just to create and update a value so I can't use each, I have to access the $link variable from my HTML/Angular code

Comment: @Thomas so why are you using http.get() if you dont want to call php page actually.

Comment: @charlietfl from server side returning string as output it is not ideal. In angularJS they have to use response.data.link that's it

Comment: that's my point...OP's code doesn't know about object with property `link`

Comment: @charlietfl sorry i cannot get you properly

Comment: @charlietfl so if i use self.link = response.data.link; instead of self.link = response.data; that should fix it? And i could use 
<?php
   $link = "http://example.com/".time();
?>
as the php?

Comment: @Thomas using time doesn't make much sense to me. You have no way to know that time belongs to specific user or what content to output for it. Not really clear exactly what you are trying to do to be honest

Comment: @charlietfl That's true, but it's very unlikely. I am making an app that gives users a search radius of where to look for a lost pet and the radius expands with time. So each user will have a different instance of the javascript and html automatically made for them. The random hexidecimal number will be appended to the link to give each user a unique link/page for their own search radius.

Comment: @charlietfl that's why i'm using php, so i can store and update that value on the server side. But I'm pretty new to Angular, would you recommend another method for this?

Comment: @Thomas no that's fine if you have the back end under control

Comment: Isn't back end just another word for server side? But I also read Angular takes care of the back end using RESTFUL or something